# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 on postForObject using rest template

Tags: spring-boot

I get a 404 error with the below code even though the url is correct and the request is successful when I try through postman. Looking forward for help sooner the better. Thank you in advance

```
public void executeExcelData() {
    System.out.println("Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    try {
        File srcFileLocation = new File(fileSrcLocationPath);
        File destFileLocation = new File(fileDestLocationPath);
        File[] srcFiles = srcFileLocation.listFiles();
        if (srcFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File f : srcFiles) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileSrcLocationPath + f.getName()));
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.iterator();
                while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIt.next();
                    if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    newComment.setPassword("Your new password is" + " " + row.getCell(0).toString());
                    newComment.setCreated_user(row.getCell(1).toString());
                    newComment.setIssue_id(row.getCell(2).toString());
                    System.out.println(newComment.toString());
                    //getIssueDetails(newComment);
                    postNewCommentToAPI(newComment);
                    File srcFile = new File(fileSrcLocationPath + f.getName());
                    File[] destFiles = destFileLocation.listFiles();
                    if (destFiles.length > 0) {
                        for (File d : destFiles) {
                            File desFile = new File(destFileLocation + "/" + d.getName());
                                copyFileUsingStream(srcFile, desFile);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "File doesnot exist in output folder");
                    }
                }
                workbook.close();
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        else {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "File doesnot exist in input folder");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occur", ex);
    }
}

public void postNewCommentToAPI(NewComment newComment) {
    try {
        String issueId = newComment.getIssue_id();
        String url = jiraUrlPath + issueId + "/" + "comment";
        createHeaders();
        JSONObject commentJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        commentJsonObject.put("body", newComment.getPassword());
        createRequestFactory();
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String> 
(commentJsonObject.toString(), createHeaders());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(createRequestFactory());
        String newCommentString = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occur", ex);
    }

}

public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(20000);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
    return requestFactory;
}

public HttpHeaders createHeaders() {
    String authStr = jiraCredentials;
    String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authStr.getBytes());
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return headers;
}

public static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

}

Below is the stacktrace:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:414) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.bot.microservice.ScheduleTask.postNewCommentToAPI(ScheduleTask.java:150) [classes/:na]
    at com.bot.microservice.ScheduleTask.executeExcelData(ScheduleTask.java:96) [classes/:na]

Comment: Everything worked fine until last few hours and api was getting updated with the post call and this error appeared without any major change in the code.

Comment: Are you able to access that rest API with the same request & response object using postman or any rest client?